# Where can I get very simple inroduction to all Artificial intelligent techniques with Real world Examples

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I know that Artificial Intelligence field is very vast and there are many books on it. But i just want to know the any resource where i can get the simple inroduction to all Artificail Intelligence techniques like

It would like to have 1 or 2 page introduction of all techniques and their examples of how they can be applied or for what purpose they can be used. I am interested in

1. Backpropagation Algoritm
2. Hebbs Law
3. Bayesian networks
4. Markov Chain Models
5. Simulated Annealing
6. Tabu Search
7. Genetic Algorithms or Evolutionary Algos

Now there are many variants and more AI techniques. And each one have many books written on them. i am unable to decide which algos i can use unless i know what they are capable of doing.

So can i find 1-2 page inroduction of them with Application examples

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are some good resources for programming Artificial Intelligence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238277/what-are-some-good-resources-for-programming-artificial-intelligence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Essentials of Metaheuristics](http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~sean/book/metaheuristics/) covers several of these - I can't promise it'll cover all of them, but I know there's good stuff on simulated annealing and genetic algorithms in there. Probably at least a few of the others, but I'd have to re-download it to check. It's available for free download.

It can be a bit light on the theory, but it'll give you a straightforward description, some explanation of when you'd want to use each, and a lot of useful pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an image on local search (= tabu search without tabu) from the [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner) manual:

[image: Local search]

I am working on similar images for Greedy algorithms, brute force, branch and bound and simulated annealing.

Answer (score 0):

As an example of Genetic Algorithms implementation I can give you [this](https://github.com/juanmf/ga).
It's an API I developed for GA, with one implementation for each operator, and one concrete example problem solved ((good) Soccer Team among ~600 players with budget restriction). Its all setup so you run it with `mvn exec:java` and watch it evolving in the console output. But you can implement your own problem structure, or even other operators (crossing, mutating, selection) methods.